# QFT background needed for AdS/CFT integrability

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, resource-recommendations, education, ads-cft

Apologies if this type of question isn't permitted.

I'm very interested in integrability in the context of AdS/CFT. I'm starting my Masters soon in a very GATIS-involved institute and would like to revise and master as much of the QFT I previously learned as possible.

My previous exposure to QFT was a two semester course covering roughly the first 7 chapters of Peskin and a little of chapter 10. I could turn the crank and calculate things but did not feel like I properly understood QFT. I am remedying that now.

In order to start understanding AdS/CFT integrability papers, how much of a background in QFT is necessary? I of course need to learn path integrals, Yang-Mills theory, SUSY, what other topics are required? Can I ignore things like QCD?